# Fuerte source install

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the currently preferred method for a complete source build of ROS Fuerte?

This URL does not seem to work.
http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=fuerte&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12985/fuerte-source-install/) by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 403 on 2012-02-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-02-11**:
It's now in two systems.  There's not good documentation yet.  I'll be writing some soon.  I'll post a link here when I write it up.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-02-27**:
I'd like to do a source install also... @tfoote have you written up this documentation yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [catkin guide](http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/). As tully says, its still in the works, but its easy enough to follow for building. There is a working rosinstaller you can build off - just add your stacks to the bottom of it:

https://raw.github.com/willowgarage/catkin/master/test/test.rosinstall

To start your rosinstall, make sure you have rosinstall updated to the latest version and run it with the --catkin option:

```
rosinstall --catkin ~/catkin https://raw.github.com/willowgarage/catkin/master/test/test.rosinstall
```

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2012-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-02-27**:
@snorri : can you edit your answer to use this link instead (more up-to-date)? http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-04-10**:
Official guide is up at http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu/Source

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-04-10**:
I think you were meaning: http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source